# Core data query returns correct values but table cell is empty

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

I am fetching data from Core Data, the returned data is correct when printed in the console. But the tableview always returns empty cells. The object exists, numberOfRowsinSection is returned with the proper count as well.
Been looking for hours, I hope its not a typo. Any help is appreciated, the code is below. I tried both valueForKey and valueForKeypath with no success
Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class HistoryViewController: UITableViewController{

@IBOutlet var historyTableView: UITableView!
var activitiesHistory: [NSManagedObject] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Past Workouts"
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "historyCell")
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Activity", in: CoreDataStack.context)
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Activity> = Activity.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    //let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Activity.timestamp), ascending: true)
    //fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        activitiesHistory = try CoreDataStack.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        //print(activitiesHistory)


    } catch  let error{
        //handle error
        print(error)
    }
}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return activitiesHistory.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let workout = activitiesHistory[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyCell", for: indexPath)
    print(workout.value(forKey: "timestamp"))
    cell.textLabel?.text = workout.value(forKey: "timestamp")as? String

    //cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
    return cell
}
 }
```

Comment: Just call tableView.reloadData() after you set activitiesHistory

Comment: Thanks, but cells are still empty.

Comment: Are you forget to add delegate and datasource?

Comment: I set delegate and datasource to that ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help! I found the solution:

The problem was that the data returned from the DB as of type "Date". The cell would simply show blank space and Xcode would show a warning or error. When I used DateFormatter() to convert the type to a formatted string, the cells displayed the data. Code below:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let workout = activities[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyCell", for: indexPath)
    let time = workout.value(forKey: "timestamp")
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM"
    let formatteddate = formatter.string(from: time as! Date)
    cell.textLabel?.text = formatteddate
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.

```
var activities: [Activity] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    addData()

    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        activities = try context.fetch(Activity.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {

    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.activities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.activities[indexPath.row].timestamp

    return cell
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q01Va.png)

Comment: Thanks! But the issue was different since I used the DATE type in my data model. Solution is posted below.